# Fourier Transform in “Syuzhet” package of R

Tags: r, fourier-transform, sentiment-analysis

I am performing sentiment analysis on movie scripts using the “Syuzhet” package in R. Below is my sample code:

```
library(syuzhet)
#Shawshank
shawshank<-get_text_as_string("D:/Movies Scripts/1_Shawshank Redemption.txt")
shawshank<-get_sentences(shawshank)
shawshank_sentiment_vector <- get_sentiment(shawshank, method="bing")

plot(shawshank_sentiment_vector, type="l", main="Plot Trajectory", xlab="Narrative Time", ylab= "Emotional Valence")

shawshank_ft_values <- get_transformed_values(shawshank_sentiment_vector, low_pass_size=3, x_reverse_len=100, scale_vals=TRUE, scale_range=FALSE)
plot(shawshank_ft_values, type ="h", main ="The Shawshank Redemption", xlab = "narrative time", ylab = "Emotional Valence", col = "red")
lines(shawshank_ft_values, type ="l", col = "dark red")
```

Data Source: http://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/movie_script.php?movie=shawshank-redemption-the

I am able to plot the sentiments using the values returned by out of the box function “get_transformed_values”.

[image]

However, I do not have a clear understanding of how the Fourier transform works. Also, in the sample codes, I have seen online most people use the “low_pass_size” parameter in this function as 3 (as used in the above sample code too). Can someone please briefly explain what these transformed values and the low pass size conceptually signify? Thank you in advance.

Comment: have you read this [blogpost](http://www.matthewjockers.net/2015/02/02/syuzhet/) of the syuzhet author?